# Bind Ctrl+Right to nextword in nano (as it is in all other apps)

Tags: editor, shortcut-keys, nano

And likewise Ctrl+Left to prevword. I read the man page of [nanorc](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.2/nanorc.5.html) and found

> bind *key function menu*

So the line `bind ^Left prevword main` would be what I want, the problem is that nano only accepts

> an alpha character or the word "Space"

so `Left` doesn't exist.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Right now I'm on natty (nano 2.2.2) but I will  upgrade nano if a later (devel?) version can do this.

Comment: in nano `v2.7.1` it works fine using the Gnome Terminal

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sadly, I don't think this is possible. I've found a thread where a nano developer [said](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.editors.nano.general/month=20040901):

> > Hi, I've searched high and low trying to find out if it's possible to 
> >     navigate through the text with CTRL left/right-key to jump word by 
> >     word...
>
> Unfortunately, no.  Meta-Space and Ctrl-Space are the only keys to do 
>   that.  This is because in text mode, there's no way for nano to tell
>   the  difference between Ctrl-Left and Left and between Ctrl-Right and
>   Right.

On [another](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.editors.nano.general/802), he added:

> because I figure that nano should work the same way  under both X
>   terminals and the console, and I have yet to find a console  that can
>   distinguish between [arrow key] and Ctrl-[arrow key].  I do  wish that
>   wasn't the case...

Comment: As sad as it is I'm gonna have to accept your answer. Cool that you not only found out but also found this question!

Comment: The latest versions of `nano` support this now. https://askubuntu.com/questions/49530/bind-ctrlright-to-nextword-in-nano-as-it-is-in-all-other-apps/907579#907579

Answer (score 7):

There is a solution to this problem. Redefine <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Left and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Right in your Terminal program to seldom-used keys, such as <kbd>F13</kbd> and <kbd>F14</kbd>.

Then in ~/.nanorc:

```
bind F13 prevword main
bind F14 nextword main
```

Now, a shortcoming, for me at least, is that it will only work when you're using the Terminal program you used for the key redefinition. For example, in my situation, this doesn't work when I'm at the physical console of my OS (in my case, FreeBSD). But I use QVT/Term from my desktop in the other room almost 100% of the time. Works like a charm.

Comment: Interesting. What terminal did you use? I looked for a setting like this in gnome-terminal and couldn't find anything. Normally I use stjerm and haven't seen anything like that either.

Comment: As I stated above, I use a product called QVT/Term. It's a simple telnet program, albeit a very cool one, that I downloaded in Aug. of 1998 directly from the company (QPC Software). Can't seem to find any new versions. I have the emulation set at 'VT220-7bit'. However, these keys **should** be redefinable in your *NIX shell. I haven't researched that yet, only because the terminal option was right in front of me.

Answer (score 3):

Install the latest version of `nano`. They have added `ctrl+left` and `ctrl+right` to move by words. (For sure v2.7.4 has this).

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the default `Ctrl-Space` and `Alt-Space` commands.