# Editing with nano, Alt is caught by the window menus, how can I fix that?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, text-editor, nano

The <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is used for many useful commands, but unfortunately it's caught by the terminal window to activate the window menus (File, Edit, ...).

I would like to either force the terminal window to pass <kbd>Alt</kbd> to the terminal or get nano to use some other key/combination (I'm using GNOME Terminal 2.32.1).

ps: There is a related, but different question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49530/bind-ctrlright-to-nextword-in-nano-as-it-is-in-all-other-apps) where it's pointed out that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> cannot be bound to "move forward a word".

Comment: that why it's a good idea to be a friend of `xterm` and `vi`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The terminal emulation handles that already. If a key combination with <kbd>ALT</kbd> is used by the terminal itself, you can just substitute <kbd>ALT</kbd> with <kbd>ESC</kbd>. For example, if you want to count characters, words and lines in nano and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is used by the terminal, just type <kbd>ESC</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

For the Alt key to work in the nano editor, run the following command:

```bsh
echo 'xterm*metaSendsEscape: true' >> ~/.Xresources
```

It will add the line to the end of your personal xterm config file.

This line makes the setting permanent for **future** xterm windows. To just change it for the currently open xterm window (and not for other or future windows), you can hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while you left-click into the xterm window. While you keep the left mouse button pressed, you select the menu item "Meta Sends Escape".