# How to unassign Alt key from window context menu in GNOME

Tags: shortcut-keys

When I use GNOME Shell, and GNOME Connection Manager program, and try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in Midnight Commander (all inside  GNOME Connection Manager), I get a window context menu opened, instead of the *search action* shortcut in MC. This is just an example: it's an issue in other programs too.

I cannot fix this with keyboard shortcuts settings as described [in this Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/30224/44179). There is no such menu item as Keyboard Shortcuts.

Also using [the trick with the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key](https://askubuntu.com/q/109293/44179) is not good, as it's a workaround rather than a real solution.

How can I simply disable this particular <kbd>Alt</kbd> key behaviour?

Comment: "Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts" is a menu item of gnome terminal. Have you look in "Settings -> Shortcuts" of Gnome Connection Manager? - I don't have it installed, so I can't check.

Comment: For Midnight Commander use Ctrl+S for the quick search instead.

Answer (score 5):

GNOME Connection Manager is intercepting the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key combinations for its own menu and refuses to pass it on to the shell it is hosting (where your MC instance is running). This is not configurable.

This is a bug in GNOME Connection Manager, or to be precise in the GUI library it uses (Gtk), so the only good solution is to go to [their site](http://kuthulu.com/gcm/?module=contact&lang=en) and report the bug.

The other approach is filing a bug with GTK about "Alt being hardcoded" but you will need a lot of charisma and endurance to convince them to make Alt configurable. All alternatives will be workarounds, of which the ESC-key trick is the most elegant.

Comment: Yes, not even Autokey can catch these combinations to enable some fixing. This is really bad. I reported this as a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1113420), if anyone wants to join the shout-out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround which actually works. (*tested on **Ubuntu 15.10** and Gnome Connection Manager **v1.1.0***)

For me, main problem was with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> which I use very often, but in GCM it shows File menu.

My solution is to modify language file (en_US.po) and remove all menu mnemonics (eg. `_File` to `File_`).

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-connection-manager/lang
sudo sed -i -e 's/"_File"/"File_"/g' -e 's/"_Edit"/"Edit_"/g' -e 's/"_View"/"View_"/g' -e 's/"_Servers"/"Servers_"/g'  -e 's/"_Help"/"Help_"/g' en_US.po
msgcat en_US.po | sudo msgfmt -o en/LC_MESSAGES/gcm-lang.mo -
```

It will remove all menu shortcuts: Alt+F, Alt+E, Alt+V, Alt+S, Alt+H.

Gnome Connection Manager has also one more hard-coded shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (opens "Add host" dialog). You can disable it as well in the `gnome-connection-manager.glade` file:

```
cd /usr/share/gnome-connection-manager/
sudo sed -i 's/(<accelerator key="a" modifiers="GDK_MOD1_MASK" signal="clicked"\/>)/<!-- \1 -->/g' gnome-connection-manager.glade
```